# How to write data to array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to write data from the database to an array. I need to write data to an array in this format:

```
$users = [
        'nurgiz'=>'1234',
        'yavdat'=>'qwerty'
    ];
```

I try to do this:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `test_auth`.`users`');
$users = [];

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $users=  $row['name'] => $row['pass'];
    echo $users;
}
```

How to implement this code correctly?

Comment: You are overwriting the $users array with every new run of the loop. Use the name property of row as an index for users, set the value to the pass property.

Comment: You have a syntax error. You should read about [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and how they're used.

Comment: What columns do you have in your table? Do not use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next simple code:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users`');
$users = [];

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $users[$row['name']] = $row['pass'];
}

print_r($users);
```

Try it on [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=fa51fd0b02d302f56161f93a50182d9d&sqlses=7b2fb7bed3870192b143bc1a5c170463&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch key-value pairs of data from your database you can do it like this:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT name, pass FROM `test_auth`.`users`');
$users = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```